# git clone extremely slow using ssh

Tags: ssh, git, openssh

Originally I could do git clone using ssh at an acceptable speed. However my ubuntu crashed, so I reinstalled using the newest version 13.04.

After I re-installed all I try to do git clone using ssh another time. But this time the average speed is about 3KB/s.

I used a none-ssh way, the speed was good. I also tried ssh -vT login@host, speed was ok:

> Transferred: sent 3136, received 49936 bytes, in 20.5 seconds.
>
> Bytes per second: sent 152.6, received 2430.4

During the process, after these debug messages there were long waits:

> debug1: identity file /home/geow812/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>
> debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = zh_CN.UTF-8

So would someone please tell me how to improve the ssh speed? Or if you need other information please tell me because I'm new to ssh and not sure which information is relevant to this question.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having similar issues. 7mb/s normally and 200kb/s via ssh

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having similar issues.

Comment: Still a problem with latest versions?

Answer (score -1):

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    
    ping -c 3 google.com
    echo
    
    sudo ifconfig eth0 up
    echo
    
    ssh -vT login@host
    echo
    
    echo "AddressFamily inet" >> ~/.ssh/config
    echo
    
    ssh -vT git@example.com
    echo
    
    echo "Checking firewall settings..."
    # List active iptables rules
    sudo iptables -L -n
    echo
    
    echo "Checking proxy settings..."
    # Check environment variables for proxy configuration
    echo "HTTP Proxy: $http_proxy"
    echo "HTTPS Proxy: $https_proxy"
    echo "FTP Proxy: $ftp_proxy"
    echo "No Proxy: $no_proxy"
    echo
    
    echo "Configuring SSH algorithm negotiation..."
    echo "Host *"
    echo "  HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521"
    echo "  KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256"
    echo "  Ciphers=aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr"
    echo
    
    echo "Compression yes" >> ~/.ssh/config
    echo
    
    echo "Using HTTPS as an alternative..."
    # Change the Git remote URL from SSH to HTTPS for the repository (replace URL)
    # git remote set-url origin https://example.com/repo.git
    echo
    
    echo "Updating Git to the latest version..."
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install git
    echo
    
    echo "SSH performance optimization completed."
```

Comment: Please explain for everyone's benefit, in your answer, what it is doing and why.